# Values for columns in ASP.NET Identity when creating manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity

Upon database initialization, I want to manually add an initial row to `AspNetUsers`:

```sql
insert AspNetUsers 
(UserId,PersonId,UserName,NormalizedUserName,Email,NormalizedEmail,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,ConcurrencyStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEnd,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount) values
(@userIdOut,@personIdOut,@adminUserName,upper(@adminUserName),@AdminEmail,upper(@AdminEmail),@true,null,newid(),null,@AdminPhone,@true,@false,null,@false,0)
```

However, when I do this, methods like `FindByNameAsync` don't work.

What I'm doing is:

1. Setting both NormalizedUserName and NormalizedEmail to **upper case**
2. Setting a random GUID for SecurityStamp
3. I'm handling the initial password on the client side.

What else should I be doing?

Comment: Define "don't work" ?

Comment: @CaiusJard It returns null

Comment: Please post code to reproduce this so we can do it on our machines and debug it

Comment: @CaiusJard There really is no code other than FindByNameAsync. If I create the user using userManager.NewUserAsync, it works, if I insert the user via database, it doesn't.

Comment: Then you did something different to what NewUserAsync does. Perhaps it inserts in another table too (roles?) and then inner joins the data. If you miss the second insert no rows will result

Comment: Last time I used the ASP.NET Membership there were multiple tables to insert rows into, Users, Membership, Application, Profile. You might wish to consult the [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs)

Comment: @DaleK That is the old version of ASP.NET identity and is no longer applicable

Comment: @AliBdeir my point is, have you checked the docs for the version you are using.